# Server send data in python

Tags: python

I'm writing a simple client server app in python, where the client is listening every type of data entering in the specific port, and I want to when receiving a data flow, send back to the connected client (which have a dinamic ip) a string, in this case "001". But when I try to send the message, it fails!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket

TCP_IP = '192.168.1.115'        
TCP_PORT = 55001   
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024      
MESSAGE = '01'  

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)    
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))     
s.listen(1)     

conn, addr = s.accept()         
print ('Connection address:', addr)      
while 1:       
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)     
    if not data: break      
    print ('received data:', data)      
    conn.send(data)  # echo       

print ('Sending data to client...')   

addr change every connection .. i cannot manage this! 

s.connect((addr, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()
```

Comment: "It fails" isn't very descriptive. What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? If there's an error message, what is it, exactly?

Comment: Why are you trying to connect back to the client when you already have a connection to the client, `conn`, which you're already perfectly able to `send` on (in the `# echo` line)?

Comment: Also, this isn't relevant to your problem, but… you do realize that this server can only accept a single connection at a time, and quits as soon as it's done with this connection, right? For a toy example for learning, that's fine, but in real life, you need to either build a `select` loop, or spawn a process/thread/greenlet for each client—or, better, use something like `asyncore`, `twisted`, `tornado`, `tulip`, or `gevent` that takes care of all the hard stuff.

Comment: so, are u telling me that i should delete the line?

Comment: yeah, i need to receive on data, and send back a message

Comment: @Alex: Delete which line? What exactly are you trying to do here? Why do you want to make a new connection to the client?

Answer (score 1):

(Connected stream) sockets are bidirectional, so there's no need to call `connect` to get a connection to the client—you already have one.

But you want to know why your code fails. And there are at least three problems with it.

First, after you call `listen` or `connect` on a `socket`, you can't call `connect` again; you will get an exception (`EISCONN` on POSIX, something equivalent on Windows). You will have to create a new `socket`.

Second, is client actually `bind`ed and `listen`ing for a connection on the same port as the server? If not, your `connect` can't work. If so, the `bind` will fail if the client and server are on the same machine.

Third, the `addr` you get back from `accept` is a `(host, port)` pair, not just a host. So, as written, you're trying to `connect((('192.168.1.115', 12345), 55001))`, which obviously isn't going to work.

Comment: Sorry, 

i've a open connection from 'ip client', socket... and i receive a data flow from client..which is stored in "data".

Now, after i receive a data flow, i want to send back the message '01' to ip client (which is stored in addr), but when i sniff the tcp packets my server .115 does not send the message that i declared  ù

Comment: @Alex: Is that a question? If so, what do you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reply to the client using the server listening socket (`s`). This is only possible in UDP Servers. Since this is a TCP Server you have to use the `conn` which is crated using `s.accept()` to communication with remote client.

Comment: I think you missed the `s.connect((addr, TCP_PORT))`. If that worked, `s` would no longer be the server listening socket, but a new TCP client socket. (Of course it _won't_ work, for the reasons I explained in my answer, but that's another story.)